# Skip items with empty values in View

Tags: 7, views

I've a view filled with events. Some events carry a date, some don't.
How can I leave out those without a date? There should be somewhere a `empty($date) ? hide($view) : break;`. But I don't know how to do this with a view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter to the View, and filter out all events where date is `NULL`.